# oracle sql group by with empty string

Tags: sql, oracle

I should group a list with empty strings. Here are 2 examples, ohne without empty strings (works well) and one with empty strings (don't work).
Any Ideas?

```
Works well
==============
Name    Bewertung   Leistung        
---------------------------------------
Jagger  234'234     <Null>
Jagger  <Null>      100'000

select Name, sum(Bewertung), sum(Leistung) from Stars
  group by Name

Name    Bewertung   Leistung        
---------------------------------------
Jagger  234'234     100'000


__/__/__/__/__/__/__/__/__/__/__/__/
Don't work
============
Name    Bewertung   WHRB    Leistung    WHRL
-------------------------------------------------------
Jagger  234'234     GBP     <Null>      <Null>
Jagger  <Null>      <Null>  100'000     GBP
Jagger  <Null>      <Null>   50'000     GBP

select Name, sum(Bewertung), WHRB, sum(Leistung), WHRL
  group by Name, WHRB, WHRL

Name    Bewertung   WHRB    Leistung    WHRL
-------------------------------------------------------
Jagger  234'234     GBP     <Null>      <Null>
Jagger  <Null>      <Null>  150'000     GBP
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is to create 2 subqueries with the unique values.

```sql
select *
from   
(
    select Name, Bewertung, WHRB 
    from stars 
    where WHRB is not null
) a
full join 
(
    select Name, Leistung, WHRL 
    from stars 
    where WHRL is not null
) b using (Name)
```

Comment: I added my table with a second 'Leistung' and it works perfectely with this. I added also a second 'WHRL' and integrated it with a sum and it works also find.  THANKS YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you want something like this  as you did not post expected output:

```
   select Name, WHRB, WHRL,sum(Bewertung), sum(Leistung)
      group by nvl(Name, rownum),Name nvl(WHRB, WHRB),WHRB, nvl(WHRL, rownum),WHRL
```

Or you can ignore null values by aggregating `WHRB, WHRL` column as well :

```
   select Name, sum(WHRB), sum(WHRL),sum(Bewertung), sum(Leistung)
      group by Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to aggregate those two columns (e.g., use `MAX`):

```
SQL> with stars (name, bewertung, whrb, leistung, whrl) as
  2    (select 'Jagger', 234234, 'GBP', to_number(null), to_char(null) from dual union all
  3     select 'Jagger', null, null, 100000, 'GBP' from dual
  4    )
  5  select name, sum(bewertung), max(whrb), sum(leistung), max(whrl)
  6  from stars
  7  group by name;

NAME   SUM(BEWERTUNG) MAX SUM(LEISTUNG) MAX
------ -------------- --- ------------- ---
Jagger         234234 GBP        100000 GBP

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work for the whole request (I added now my table above). When I have more than one 'Leistung', I need the sum. May my first request wasn't clear enough.  But Thank you anyway!

Comment: Well, that's what happens when you don't provide enough information :) No problem, I'm glad you got the answer.